# Using for loop to filter data frame with different groups in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, filter

If I have a data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(
  name = c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8", "n9", "n10"),
  color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "green", "green"),
weight = c(53, 34, 63, 25, 45, 24, 66, 12, 45, 8),
  gender = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,1 ,1 , 0, 1, 0))
```

How would I use the `for` loop function in R to filter 'weight' values that are +10 from the mean **for each 'color**'? So I would get an output of all the rows that had a weight +10 from the mean for each of the separate 'colours'.

I know `d[d$weight > mean(d$weight) + (10 + sd(d$weight)), ]` would give me the rows that fit this criteria of the entire sample, but I'm trying to find the values for each 'color' separately since each 'color' has a different sd value.

I'm trying to understand the `for` loops in R.

Comment: Hi, why are you using `sd` in you example if you want to get the mean? Why do you need to use a for loop (generally better to avoid them in `R`)?

Comment: Sorry I left that part out by accident, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

using a `for` loop for this is a terrible idea, but since you asked...

```
d <- data.frame(
  name = c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8", "n9", "n10"),
  color = c("blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "red", "green", "green"),
  weight = c(53, 34, 63, 25, 45, 24, 66, 12, 45, 8),
  gender = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,1 ,1 , 0, 1, 0)) 

d[d$weight > (10 + sd(d$weight)), ]

for (color in unique(d$color)) {
  subd <- d[d$color == color, ]
  print(subd[subd$weight > (10 + sd(subd$weight)), ])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @cj-yetman that doing this with `for` loops is not ideal. A better approach could be to use `dplyr` grouping functionality. Something like:

```
library(dplyr)
d2 <- d %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  mutate(avg_w = mean(weight, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  filter(abs(weight - avg_w) <= 10)

> d2
Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
Groups: color [2]

    name  color weight gender avg_w
  <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     n2   blue     34      0  40.4
2     n5    red     45      1  40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the base R `by` function which does exactly as you need: running same operations across different levels of dataframe, here being `color` values. The return is a list of dataframes that you can then run `do.call(rbind, ...)` for one final dataframe:

```
mean_subsetsdflist <- by(d, d$color, function(i) 
     i[i$weight > (mean(i$weight) + (10 + sd(i$weight))), ])

mean_subsetdf <- do.call(rbind, mean_subsetsdflist)
```